# Is it correct to say "a bigger brother should concede a bigger piece of cake to his younger brother" in everyday English?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-request, phrase-choice

I know that in Western culture, when there is a cake, mom will cut it in half and give them to her 2 sons each. So, the big brother will get one and the little brother will get one.

But in other cultures, mom will cut it into 2 pieces. One is big and one is small. She will give the big one to the little brother and smaller one to the big brother.

Is it correct to say "**a bigger brother should concede a bigger piece of cake to his younger brother**" in everyday English?

Or,  "**a bigger brother should give away a bigger piece of cake to his younger brother**"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both your options are grammatically correct, but neither of them is phrased how a native English speaker would phrase it, though the second one is closer than the first. It would be more colloquial as something like “A big brother should let his younger brother have the larger slice of cake”.